# How could I manipulate (X or (Y implies Z)) using laws of predicate calculus?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am trying to simplify / transform the following expression (apologies for formatting, I'm new on this forum):

$$[X \vee (Y \Rightarrow Z)]$$

I figured out it can be reduced down to $[X \vee (\neg Y) \vee Z]$, although I would like to see the steps that are involved in the process.

Any ideas on how to go about it?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: You use the fact that $Y \Rightarrow Z $ is equivalent to $\neg Y \vee Z$